# AJAX returns blank page and prints the code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

AJAX function should return HTML inside the div checkout-wrap in the same page. Instead, it redirects to a blank page and prints the array

Code in Controller:

```
return ['success'=>1, 'msg'=> trans('app.payment_received_msg'), 'response' => $this->payment_success_html()];
```

What is printed:

```
{"success":1,"msg":"Success","response":" <div class=\"payment-received\">\n    <h1> <i class=\"fa fa-check-circle-o\"><\/i> Thank You<\/h1>\n    \n    <a href=\"http:\/\/localhost\" class=\"btn btn-filled\">Home<\/a>\n   <\/div>"}
```

I'm using Laravel.

Ajax Function

```
$.ajax({
    url : '{{route('pg_submit')}}',
    type: "POST",
    data: form, 
success : function (data) {
    if (data.success == 1){
       $('.checkout-wrap').html(data.response);
       toastr.success(data.msg, '@lang('app.success')', toastr_options);
    }
},
error   : function ( jqXhr, json, errorThrown ) {
    var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
    var errorsHtml= '';
    $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
        errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
    });
    toastr.error( errorsHtml , "Error " + jqXhr.status +': '+ errorThrown);
}
});
```

Route pg_submit

```
Route::post('checkout/pg', ['as' => 'pg_submit','uses' => 'CampaignsController@pgRedirect']);
```

Comment: do you have a form on the page?

Comment: yeah, and the form data is being sent to controller, the main problem is the return

Comment: sounds like the form is just submitting like normal ... not ajax

Comment: Maybe! I'll check it

Comment: @lagbox Thank You! You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have action & method attribute on your form like

`<form action="/checkout/pg" method="post">`

You can remove the attributes and give the id or class to your from like this

`<form id="pg_submit">`

Than you can add or modify your script like this

```
$('#pg_submit').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : '{{route('pg_submit')}}',
        type: "POST",
        data: form, 
        success : function (data) {
            if (data.success == 1){
               $('.checkout-wrap').html(data.response);
               toastr.success(data.msg, '@lang('app.success')', toastr_options);
            }
        },
        error   : function ( jqXhr, json, errorThrown ) {
            var errors = jqXhr.responseJSON;
            var errorsHtml= '';
            $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
            });
            toastr.error( errorsHtml , "Error " + jqXhr.status +': '+ errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```